# i18nextify doesn't translate in javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, i18next

Following [this](https://github.com/i18next/i18nextify/tree/master/example) example I was able to add locales to my application and to translate strings in html/Jade.

For example, given this translation.json file:

```
{
    "test": "prova"
}
```

I can put it in my Jade page:

```
label test
```

Right now I'm using the same configuration options of the link above.
What doesn't work is the translation in a javascript function, example:

```
script(type="text/javascript").
    require([
        "dojo/ready",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/request/xhr",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (ready, dom, on, xhr) {
        console.log("dom ready");
        console.log("test");
    });
```

it doesn't translate the string "test" to "prova" like it does few lines above in the html code.
In the github example the author does something similar:

```
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
```

where "CLICK ME" is a string available in the translation file.
Hence I guessed it should translate also my

```
console.log("test");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you use https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/i18n.html ?

Comment: @KirillStepanov I tried but I had some headaches and I wasn't able to translate strings hardcoded in html. Surely it was my fault, but the documentation seems a bit harder to read. Anyway, I can surely give it another try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample does work as we append that node to the dom -> i18nextify used virtualdom implementation and automatically parses and translate dom content.

You can use the underlying i18next instance to translate javascript content directly.

`console.log(i18nextify.i18next.t('dom ready'));` -> for docs see http://i18next.com

Comment: It works. I was afraid about the dojo framework and I didn't realize it was something so easy to fix.